# R: Dynamic assignment to function argument based on other arguments

Tags: r, function, variable-assignment

I am writing a function with two arguments and I want the default vector assigned to an argument to be a vector of `NA` of the same length as the input to the other argument of arbitrary length. In psuedo-code, I want `my_function <- function(foo, bar = rep(NA, length(foo))){}`. The issue with this approach is that `foo` is not an initialized object and so `length(foo)` throws an error. Is there some way of doing this without first initializing the object for assigning to the `foo` argument?

Comment: Why do you say "`length(foo)` throws an error"? As shown in my answer, as you've described your problem, it doesn't throw an error. Is there something else going on in your code that might cause the issue? Or was it perhaps an assumption that it would throw an error? If you actually got an error, could you update your question to show what the error message was, and the fuller context it occurred in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing does not throw an error:

```
f <- function(foo, bar = rep(NA, length(foo))) {
    print(foo)
    print(bar)
}

f(1:10)

 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: I actually mistyped in my working example and it worked. Although, I am surprised this works since doesn't length(foo) require there to be a foo object prior to its evaluation, but all of the arguments are evaluated at once?

Comment: @user3614648 The arguments are actually not evaluated all at once; such arguments are actually **promises**, which are evaluated only when accessed. For more information, see, e.g. [this excerpt](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#function-arguments) from Hadley Wickham's Advanced R.